# trying to get category with a user has not subscribe to

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

am trying to display list of categories a user has not subscribe to , and i could not get it kindly assist am using this package for the subscribtion https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-subscribe

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Feed;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Livewire\Component;

class NewsFeed extends Component
{
    public $category;

    public function render()
    {
        $category_id = $this->category;
        return view('livewire.feed.news-feed',[

            'cats' => Category::whereDoesntHave('subscribers',  function ($query) use ($category_id) {
                     $query->where('subscribable_id', $category_id);
             })->inRandomOrder()->take(5)->get(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it have a many-to-many morph relationship?

Comment: yes it has morph to many

Comment: you would need to filter by the subscriber (user) not the category